# Why asp.net core fails to de-serialize this json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
dotnet --version
2.2.300
```

Create a empty folder. In this folder run

```
dotnet new webapi
```

Go to `Startup.cs` and comment out `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` Run:

```
dotnet run
```

Wait for the process to start up. Assuming that you are on a newer build of Windows 10 and have `curl.exe` that comes out of the box with Windows 10 run:

```
 curl.exe http://localhost:5000/api/values -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{}"
```

Observe the result:

```
{"errors":{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"0HLN4K718DVA4:00000001"}
```

Trace Id will be different in your case.

Here is some debug output from a similar but *different* application. The difference is logging configuration, slightly different, but similar `POST` payload, slightly different but similar `Content-Type` header,  different routes, ports.

```
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Request matched endpoint 'test.Controllers.ValuesController.Post (test)'
[14:02:03 INF 7] Executing endpoint 'test.Controllers.ValuesController.Post (test)'
[14:02:03 INF 7] Route matched with {action = "Post", controller = "Values"}. Executing controller action with signature Void Post(System.String) on controller test.Controllers.ValuesController (test).
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Execution plan of authorization filters (in the following order): ["None"]
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Execution plan of resource filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter"]
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Execution plan of action filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter (Order: -3000)", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter (Order: -2000)"]
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Execution plan of exception filters (in the following order): ["None"]
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Execution plan of result filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ClientErrorResultFilter (Order: -2000)"]
[14:02:03 VRB 7] Resource Filter: Before executing OnResourceExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.
[14:02:03 VRB 7] Resource Filter: After executing OnResourceExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Attempting to bind parameter 'value' of type 'System.String' ...
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Attempting to bind parameter 'value' of type 'System.String' using the name '' in request data ...
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Rejected input formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonPatchInputFormatter' for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Selected input formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter' for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Connection id "0HLN4KB7M6AHT", Request id "0HLN4KB7M6AHT:00000001": started reading request body.
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Connection id "0HLN4KB7M6AHT", Request id "0HLN4KB7M6AHT:00000001": done reading request body.
[14:02:03 DBG 7] JSON input formatter threw an exception.
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Done attempting to bind parameter 'value' of type 'System.String'.
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Done attempting to bind parameter 'value' of type 'System.String'.
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Attempting to validate the bound parameter 'value' of type 'System.String' ...
[14:02:03 DBG 7] Done attempting to validate the bound parameter 'value' of type 'System.String'.
[14:02:03 VRB 7] Action Filter: Before executing OnActionExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter.
[14:02:03 VRB 7] Action Filter: After executing OnActionExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter.
[14:02:03 VRB 7] Action Filter: Before executing OnActionExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter.
[14:02:04 DBG 7] The request has model state errors, returning an error response.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Action Filter: After executing OnActionExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter.
[14:02:04 DBG 7] Request was short circuited at action filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter'.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Action Filter: Before executing OnActionExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Action Filter: After executing OnActionExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Result Filter: Before executing OnResultExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Result Filter: After executing OnResultExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Result Filter: Before executing OnResultExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ClientErrorResultFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Result Filter: After executing OnResultExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ClientErrorResultFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Before executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult.
[14:02:04 DBG 7] List of registered output formatters, in the following order: ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.HttpNoContentOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StringOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StreamOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter"]
[14:02:04 DBG 7] No information found on request to perform content negotiation.
[14:02:04 DBG 7] Attempting to select the first output formatter in the output formatters list which supports a content type from the explicitly specified content types '["application/problem+json", "application/problem+xml"]'.
[14:02:04 DBG 7] Selected output formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter' and content type 'application/problem+json' to write the response.
[14:02:04 INF 7] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails'.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] After executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Result Filter: Before executing OnResultExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ClientErrorResultFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Result Filter: After executing OnResultExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ClientErrorResultFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Result Filter: Before executing OnResultExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Result Filter: After executing OnResultExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Resource Filter: Before executing OnResourceExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.
[14:02:04 VRB 7] Resource Filter: After executing OnResourceExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.
[14:02:04 INF 7] Executed action test.Controllers.ValuesController.Post (test) in 453.5132ms
[14:02:04 INF 7] Executed endpoint 'test.Controllers.ValuesController.Post (test)'
[14:02:04 DBG 7] Connection id "0HLN4KB7M6AHT" completed keep alive response.
[14:02:04 INF 7] Request finished in 589.1984ms 400 application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
```

It appears that the culprit is `JsonInputFormatter` which is triggered because of the `application/json` content type.

Questions:

1. Why is this happening? I would expect it to work, since `{}` is valid json.
2. If you put a break point in your Visual Studio on the `Post` method it will not be hit. So it does not seem that you even can read the raw value and parse the json yourself. How do I by pass JsonInputFormatter, given that I don't control the `Content-Type` header from the request?

To reproduce this you can use your favorite tool, not just curl, it is also reproducible with Postman, Fiddler, and I assume others.

Comment: Let me know if the duplicate isn't suitable, and I'll reopen the question :)

Comment: Also set the Accept header. Content-Type is what language you speak, Accept is what language you can hear :)

Comment: @Davesoft I cannot not control what clients do. I only want to be able to process what ever is sent by client my way instead of asp.net decided that it knows better ;). The solution to that is not to use `FromBody` and read and parse response string manually.